# Is it possible to fill templates (.xls, .pdf, ppt) with Birt or alternatives?

Tags: java, report, reporting, birt

is it possible to fill a predefined template file via birt reporting?

- .xls for exmaple: The template should have defined the column headers (nicly formatted) and some other stuff like the date of creation, the user, some legal notice, ...
- .pdf on the other hand should define id-fields that are to be filled with data
- .ppt as the last and may be trickiest one should ideally be also be useable as .pdf but as far as I know .ppt itself does not provide IDs for its fields and therefore a workaround must be used to identify the places to be filled

Are there alternatives to birt that might be able to do that?

I'm very curious about the answers :-)

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

[Templater](http://templater.info/) supports docx and xlsx. From there we are generating PDFs using LibreOffice.

Being author of the tool, I highly recommend it :)

There are plenty of examples on site if you are interested.

Answer (score 0):

It could be very challenging to hit a predifined Excle format with the native BIRT Excel emitter, there are several after market Excel emitters that might help you get there.

The easier way is to set up your BIRT report to export with the format you want, then save report and use it as foundation for recreating the next report.  You can use grids, and master pages to get just the layout you want, then plug in report pieces.

You can also use the library to save grids, tables & data sets that you use over and over.

Answer (score 0):

The Spudsoft XLS Emitter for BIRT (which is builtin with BIRT 4.3.1) supports this for XLS.

We are using this feature and it works like a charm.

However, BIRT does not support "filling" doc or ppt docs.

Templating engines usually have difficulties to support master-detail (or master-detail-detail) relationships. This is due to the somewhat stupid implementation of tables in MS Word.